# bivariate normal distribution & change of units

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I need to find the bivariate normal CDF at the point (1 cm, 1 cm), i.e. the half-open interval $[-\infty,1] \times [-\infty,1] $ ,  where cm = centimeter, with mean = 0,  covariance = Id.

mvncdf( x = [1cm 1cm] , mean = 0 , cov = Id ) = 0.7079

Of course, 1 centimeter = 10 millimeters, so "equivalently" i could calculate

mvncdf( x = [10 mm  10 mm] , mean = 0 , cov = Id*10mm ) =  0.9984

**Philosophically, why are these not equal?**

Examining the density function of the bivariate normal distribution, it is perfectly obvious that the change of variable calculation is non-trivial and "explains", **in the algebraic sense**,  the difference in CDF values.

However, **geometrically**, the half-open plane   $[-\infty,1cm] \times [-\infty,1cm] $  =   $[-\infty,10mm] \times [-\infty,10mm] $, and $\sigma = 1cm = 10mm$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct calculations *are* equal, you just didn't do correct calculations. (So, philosophically, there's no basis on which you should expect the wrong calculation to give the same answer as the original one.)

From [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) $\text{Var}(kX)=k^2\text{Var}(X)$.

Similarly $\text{Cov}(aX,bY) = ab\,\text{Cov}(X,Y)$. Both can be proved from their definitions in terms of expectation.

[In the multivariate case, $\text{Var}(AX) = A\text{Var}(X)A^\top$, though this also follows from the above]

So your variance-covariance matrix in $\text{cov} = I\times 10\text{mm}$ should instead be $\text{cov} = I\times 100\text{mm}^2$